# How to save the results of a Pivot to a common table expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote this query, and the inner part works fine, but when I try to run the 'with' line I get:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
with Cheese as(
    select * from (
        Select a.ID,c.Data,c.Name
        from Account as a
        Left join AccountContacts AS ac on ac.AccountID=a.ID
        left join Contact AS c on ac.AccountID=c.ID
        where a.ID in(30176)
    ) as d
    pivot (max(d.Data) for d.Name in ([email],[phone])) as p
    where p.email is not null or p.phone is not null
)
```

This has to be a syntax error, but I'm just not seeing it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a CTE, you have to use it in the following expression.  Therefore, just add the following line at the end after your closing parenthesis.

```
SELECT * FROM cheese
```